# Solving $\mathbb{E}_X[\log (a + X)] = b$ to $a$

Tags: integration, roots

I'm trying to solve the equation

$$ \mathbb{E}_X[\log (a + X)] = b$$

to $a$ where $b>0$ and $X$ is a positive random variable distributed according to $P(X)$. The solution can be written as a function of the moments of $X$, or any other statistic of $X$.

Is this possible? I'm struggling to understand what transformation would even help.

In my case $P(X) = (\alpha - 1) X^{-\alpha}$, $\alpha > 2$, such that $\mathbb{E}_X[\log X] = 1/(\alpha - 1)$.

Comment: There is no reason to expect a tractable explicit formula in the general case. What makes you think there could exist one? Are you interested in a specific case?

Comment: @Did, yes, I'm not sure it exists. I added the explicit formula of $P(X)$, in case it helps.

Comment: Then, integrating by parts $$E(\log(a+X))=\int_1^\infty\log(a+x)\frac{\alpha-1}{x^\alpha}dx$$ yields $$E(\log(a+X))=\log a+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{a^{n+1}(n+\alpha-2)},$$ and the sum in the RHS has some quite intractable formulations as values of Hurwitz Lerch transcendant functions estimated at $-1/a$.

Comment: @did, sounds interesting enough to proceed. Would you convert that to an answer with more details on the "yields"? It may not look that simple to others.

Comment: Numerically, the solution is very close to $\log(2+a)$ (I'm interested in large $a$). Thanks a lot, this solved my problem!

Comment: There is a typo in my previous comment. If $a<1$, use $$\int\log(a+x)\frac{\alpha-1}{x^\alpha}dx=-\frac{\log(a+x)}{x^\alpha}+{}{}{}{}{}{}{}\int\frac1{a+x}\frac1{x^\alpha}dx$$ and $$\frac1{a+x}\frac1{x^\alpha}=\sum_{n\geqslant0}\frac{(-1)^na^n}{x^{n+1+\alpha}}$$ hence...

Comment: Another remark is that $X\geqslant1$ almost surely hence $E(\log(a+X))\geqslant\log(a+1)$ and that $\log$ is concave hence $E(\log(a+X))\leqslant\log(a+E(X))=\log(a+(\alpha-1)/(\alpha-2))=\log(a+1+{}{}{}{}{}1/(\alpha-2))$. These are tight bounds if $a$ or $\alpha$ is large.